# Powershell to display greater than 5 seconds

Tags: powershell

I want to display the seconds and must be greater than 5 seconds.

> ```
> RM_2123_0015_15728657.log:***** SQL Statement Prepare Time 0.000 seconds *****
> RM_1213_0015_15728657.log:***** SQL Statement Execute Time  0.002 seconds *****
> RM_1231_0015_15728657.log:***** SQL Statement Initial Fetch  0.001 seconds *****
> RM_1212_0015_15728657.log:***** SQL Statement Prepare Time 0.000 seconds *****
> RM_1111_0015_15728657.log:***** SQL Statement Execute Time 7.002 seconds *****
> RM_1232_0015_15728657.log:***** SQL Statement Initial Fetch Time 10.001 seconds *****
> ```

My expected output is:

> ```
> 7.002
> 10.001
> ```

Code:

```
Get-Content input.txt | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "[^0-9]", ""} > output.txt
```

Comment: Your expected output seems to contradict the question. Do you want only the time values or the last 3 words?

Comment: please, fix your formatting ... the data lines are just one blob at the moment.

Comment: I want to display only numbers "7.002" and "10.001"

Comment: I'd suggest to start by not removing the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
# example input array; you can replace this with Get-Content
# to read from a file, etc.
$inputData = @(
  "RM_2123_0015_15728657.log:***** SQL Statement Prepare Time 0.000 seconds *****"
  "RM_1213_0015_15728657.log:***** SQL Statement Execute Time  0.002 seconds *****"
  "RM_1231_0015_15728657.log:***** SQL Statement Initial Fetch  0.001 seconds *****"
  "RM_1212_0015_15728657.log:***** SQL Statement Prepare Time 0.000 seconds *****"
  "RM_1111_0015_15728657.log:***** SQL Statement Execute Time 7.002 seconds *****"
  "RM_1232_0015_15728657.log:***** SQL Statement Initial Fetch Time 10.001 seconds *****"
)

$inputData | Select-String '\d+\.\d{3}' | ForEach-Object {
  $result = $_.Matches[0].Groups[0].Value
  if ( $result -as [Int] -gt 5 ) {
    $result
  }
}
```

Append something like `| Out-File Results.txt` after the last `}` to write the outputs to a file.